# Style Primefaces fileupload button

Tags: css, primefaces

I'm trying to stylize the Primefaces fileUpload control to look like a regular command button.  I've got as close as you see in the screen shot but I am unable to get the button labeled "Load" to line up with the other buttons.  I marked up my screen shot with a red arrow showing the button needs to move up a few pixels.

[image]

here is my CSS and xhtml that got me to this point. I've tried various deviations but no luck.

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    border: none;
}
.ui-fileupload {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
}
.ui-fileupload-content {
    display: none;  
}


<p:toolbar>
    <f:facet name="left">

        <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-disk">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{calculator.file}" />
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{calculator.handleFileUpload}"
            label="Load" mode="advanced" update="@all" auto="true"
            sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt)$/" />

        <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="MS Word"
            icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{calculator.Poi()}" />
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is even more simple...

```
.ui-fileupload-buttonbar .ui-button {
    top: -1px;
}
```

In many cases the answer above **is relevant** (it is here to... the !important should be prevented and that can be done by applying more specific css selectors)

Comment: Ahh I understand your other answer, now that you mention the !important.  I can also clean up by adding id attribute and being more specific.  Anyway, the "top -1px" was what I was after

Answer (score 0):

Make your css selector more specific than the one that actually applies the styling now. E.g. add an id attribute to the button and use that in the selector (combining with a class you already have makes it even [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity))

Comment: I'm looking for the CSS that will shift this Button, which is generated by the fileUpload tag.   I think your answer is generic to CSS and not really addressing my issue.  Let me know if I need to be clearer in my question.